# Split text file into blocks and save

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk, split

I have a big text file saved in the name test.txt.Now i want to split the big text files into blocks at `...` symbol and want to save in the name same as what is there after `/home/niu/` . (In the data example below i need the blocks of data to be saved in  `20190630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt` for the first block, `20180630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt` for second block and `20190830_093410_1.5_29_PCK.txt` for third block.

Thus i tried the code below:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in 'test.txt'
do
split -l '...'
done
```

It does not work: i hope somebody will help me.Thanks.

My data saved in test.txt is given below:

```
    ...........................................................................................................   
    /home/niu/20190630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 470.2359935984357 41573823894247.63 53.46648291467124 216 1 0.1
    /home/niu/20190630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 13.124782961287574 219608788311302.7 53.46425102814092 219 1 0.6
    /home/niu/20190630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 4.092419925137149 12174862157739.746 53.44206693334351 291 1 1.1
    ...........................................................................................................
    /home/niu/20180630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 2.241494955966288 363350265475740.4 53.36874778729164 219 1 0.1
    /home/niu/20180630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 1.6671382966847936 282579486756.3921 53.234249504389624 218 1 2.1
    /home/niu/20180630_073410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 1.4410832347641427 17729080367.579777 53.06935945567802 216 1 2.6
    ...........................................................................................................
    /home/niu/20190830_093410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 1.2367527642969733 5141.577700615736 52.776493933960644 127 0 3.6
    /home/niu/20190830_093410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 1.171644866817557 3279.978138771641 52.65760209064783 135 0 4.1
    /home/niu/20190830_093410_1.5_29_PCK.txt 1.120249969361367 2441.45977994814 52.54882982584634 105 0 4.6
```

Comment: are the rows in the file ordered by the first column (ie, by the directory/file name)? do you actually have lines of `.................` in the file? do all lines start with a directory/file name and of the same format `<directory>/*.*.txt`? given the sample set of input, please update your question with the desired output (eg, 3x new files? and display the content of each file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/\.\.\./{close(out); next} {split($1, a, "/"); out=a[4]; print > out}' file
```

You can use this awk. I have assumed that dots (`...`) exist only in the separating lines, also all the other lines starts with `/home/niu/filename.txt`, from where we get the output filename. If this is not the case, please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'[ /]' '
!NF || /^\.+/{
  next
}
out_file!=$4{
  close(out_file)
  out_file=$4
}
{
  print >> (out_file)
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F'[ /]' '             ##Starting awk program from here and setting space and / for all lines.
!NF || /^\.+/{             ##Checking condition if number of fields is NULL OR line starting from dot then do following.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
out_file!=$4{              ##Checking condition if prev is NOT equal to out_file then do following.
  close(out_file)          ##Closing file in back end to avoid too many files opened error here.
  out_file=$4              ##Setting out_file as 4th field here.
}
{
  print >> (out_file)      ##Printing current line to out_file output file.
}' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***EDIT:*** As per OP there could be lines starting with spaces so in that case try.

```
awk -F'/' '
!NF || /^\./{
  next
}
{
  split($4,arr," ")
}
out_file!=arr[1]{
  close(out_file)
  out_file=arr[1]
}
{
  print >> (out_file)
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use csplit like this:

```
csplit test.txt '/^\./' {*}
```